# Pyinstaller: subprocess.check_output giving error in noconsole mode

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to make exe file.
`pyinstaller  --onefile --noconsole --icon ico.ico shell.py` 
 Inside my program I am using `subprocess.check_output()` function to execute my command through cmd.
The program runs well in console but in `--noconsole` it gives an error and program terminate.
How can I run `subprocess.check_output()` in noconsole?

Comment: I mean I'm not entirely sure, but wouldn't `noconsole` imply there's no output to check, hence the error?

Comment: Yes, due to  noconsole the subprocess.check_output()  is unable to run.
How to overcome this problem, any idea??

Comment: `subprocess` needs a `console`, therefore the Question is **why** would you **not allow** a `console`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the errors and the input of the `check_output()` function to nothing (null).

In python 2 and earlier versions of python3 you can do that by opening the `devnull` file in the `os` library while in the new versions of python 3 you can do it using `subprossess.DEVNULL`.

For examples visit:

- [python 2 and earlier versions of python3](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/937/os.devnull)
- [new versions of python 3](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/57081/subprocess.DEVNULL)